# Gaussian Curvature of $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, curvature

The Gaussian curvature of the sphere $ S^2=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$ is obtained via taking the determinant of the derivative of the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y,z), \ $ which is $1$.

I'd like to derive the same result using the formula for sectional curvature to understand if I got the hang of this:

$$k(R\cdot S^2) = \frac{\langle R(X,Y)Y, X \rangle}{\langle X,X\rangle\langle Y,Y\rangle-\langle X,Y\rangle^2}  =\frac{\langle ([\nabla_X, \nabla_Y]Y-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Y, X \rangle}{\langle X,X\rangle\langle Y,Y\rangle-\langle X,Y\rangle^2} $$

If we take $X=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}, \ Y=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}, \ $ where:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=\left(1,0,\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \right), \quad \frac{\partial }{\partial y}=\left(0,1,\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \right)$$

If we set $n=\left(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \right), \ $ then:
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(1,0,\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right)-\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(0,1,\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right), n\right\rangle n=
 $$
$$
\left(0,0,\frac{y^2-1}{(1-x^2-y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)-n\left\langle n, \left(0,0,\frac{y^2-1}{(1-x^2-y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)\right \rangle
 $$

The calculation get a bit cumbersome, but I wanted to know if I got the gist right.

Comment: The determinant of the map? For the rest, maybe spherical coordinates would be less cumbersome.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, we can take the determinant of the identity map using Gauss curvature.

Comment: Yes you can take the derivative of the identity map, only for the unit sphere though (since the identity map is exactly the Gauss map is this case)

Comment: It’s the derivative of the map, as a map from the sphere to the sphere. It is not the identity map,on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, I meant the determinant of the derivative, otherwise the determinant might not be defined for general maps.

Comment: @TedShifrin I just wanted to know if I was going in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to learn and work out things in a undergraduate book on surfaces before going to the definition of the Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: @TedShifrin Something in particular I'm missing? Or is it just the spherical coordinates?

Comment: I feel strongly that to understand the Riemann curvature tensor, one should first understand curvature of surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ and what it means geometrically. How is this curvature tensor connected to the determinant of the derivative of the Gauss map?

Comment: @TedShifrin We know that sectional curvature and Gauss curvature coincide for surfaces thanks to the Theorema Egregium. The first is what I'm trying to compute, the second is given by taking the determinant of the derivative of the Gauss map.